# Bootstrap 4: Checkbox text on the left, checkbox on the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, bootstrap-4

It seems simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have a checkbox with text, and I need the text to stand on the left, checkbox on the right. How can I do this?

Here's my code:

```css
.custom-control-description {
  color: #009fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-indicator {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 2px solid #cdc9ca;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form>
<div class="checkbox-wrap d-flex justify-content-end p-2 mb-2">
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <span class="custom-control-description">All Pages</span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
</label>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add position attribute to the styling of `custom-control-indicator`.

```
 .custom-checkbox .custom-control-indicator {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 2px solid #cdc9ca;
    background: #fff;
 }
```

Comment: Oh okay! That looks promising, but how can I make the text go to the far left because this is what's happening now: http://pokit.org/get/img/8840fe1f0f4612c98ac16e2d9666d9c9.jpg Wait, I'll update my code, give me a sec.

Comment: simply put `margin left: 5px` or more I don't know how far they should move. @Retros And please accept the answer if that is what you wanted.

Comment: I'll accept the answer, no problem. Because he really solved that problem. Thanks, @VipulSingh. But can you please take a look at my snippet now?

Comment: you're using `justify-content-end` as a class, that is why it is in the right corner.Use `justify-content-start`.

Comment: Yeah, and I've tried that one too, but they remain stuck to each other for some reason.

Comment: what's the final solution? looking for that but not able to find it out

Answer (score -2):

try the below code , just place the text inside the label

```html
  <label >
        <span>Text goes here....</span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
```

Comment: just see the snippet output ...why post has been down voted.. can i know the reason please???